# Running Hadoop: insufficient memory for the Java Runtime Environment to continue

Tags: java, linux, hadoop

I have a 32 bit linux system running on 3gb ram.When i tried to run hadoop example it failed saying insufficient memory to allocate for jre.The result generated is:

```
hadoop jar mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-examples-*.jar grep input output ‘dfs[a-z.]+’
15/01/11 10:17:04 INFO client.RMProxy: Connecting to ResourceManager at /127.0.0.1:8032
15/01/11 10:17:05 WARN mapreduce.JobSubmitter: No job jar file set.  User classes may not be found. See Job or Job#setJar(String).
15/01/11 10:17:05 INFO input.FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 7
15/01/11 10:17:06 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: number of splits:7
15/01/11 10:17:06 INFO Configuration.deprecation: mapred.job.name is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.name

15/01/11 10:17:06 INFO Configuration.deprecation: mapreduce.map.class is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.map.class
15/01/11 10:17:06 INFO Configuration.deprecation: mapred.input.dir is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.input.fileinputformat.inputdir
15/01/11 10:17:06 INFO Configuration.deprecation: mapreduce.reduce.class is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.reduce.class
15/01/11 10:17:06 INFO Configuration.deprecation: mapreduce.outputformat.class is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.outputformat.class
15/01/11 10:17:06 INFO Configuration.deprecation: mapred.output.value.class is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.output.value.class
15/01/11 10:17:06 INFO Configuration.deprecation: mapred.output.dir is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.output.fileoutputformat.outputdir
15/01/11 10:17:06 INFO Configuration.deprecation: mapred.working.dir is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.working.dir
15/01/11 10:17:06 INFO Configuration.deprecation: mapreduce.combine.class is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.combine.class
15/01/11 10:17:06 INFO Configuration.deprecation: mapred.map.tasks is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.maps
15/01/11 10:17:06 INFO Configuration.deprecation: user.name is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.user.name
15/01/11 10:17:06 INFO Configuration.deprecation: mapred.output.key.class is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.output.key.class
15/01/11 10:17:07 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: Submitting tokens for job: job_1420951126090_0001
15/01/11 10:17:07 INFO mapred.YARNRunner: Job jar is not present. Not adding any jar to the list of resources.
15/01/11 10:17:07 INFO impl.YarnClientImpl: Submitted application application_1420951126090_0001 to ResourceManager at /127.0.0.1:8032
15/01/11 10:17:07 INFO mapreduce.Job: The url to track the job: http://:8088/proxy/application_1420951126090_0001/
15/01/11 10:17:07 INFO mapreduce.Job: Running job: job_1420951126090_0001
15/01/11 10:17:16 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_1420951126090_0001 running in uber mode : false
15/01/11 10:17:16 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 0% reduce 0%
Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM warning: INFO: os::commit_memory(0xa7b5d000, 32768, 1) failed; error='Cannot allocate memory' (errno=12)
#
# There is insufficient memory for the Java Runtime Environment to continue.
# Native memory allocation (mmap) failed to map 32768 bytes for committing reserved memory.
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# /usr/local/hadoop-2.2.0/share/hadoop/hs_err_pid5496.log
#
# Compiler replay data is saved as:
# /usr/local/hadoop-2.2.0/share/hadoop/replay_pid5496.log
```

Is it because of my hardware of configuration or some setup error in hadoop?

Comment: Did you check the error logs mentioned above?

Comment: What kind of data are you pumping through it?  If you're doing anything semi-serious with Hadoop, you'll want at least 32GB of memory.

Comment: yes the log file says:Possible reasons:
#   The system is out of physical RAM or swap space
#   In 32 bit mode, the process size limit was hit
# Possible solutions:
#   Reduce memory load on the system
#   Increase physical memory or swap space
#   Check if swap backing store is full
#   Use 64 bit Java on a 64 bit OS
#   Decrease Java heap size (-Xmx/-Xms)
#   Decrease number of Java threads
#   Decrease Java thread stack sizes (-Xss)
#   Set larger code cache with -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=

Comment: @PratikSharma all good suggestions, did you try any of them or reduce the heap size?

Comment: @PeterLawrey well the problem of because of low virtual memory so i created a swap file of 2gb, which solved the problem

Answer (score 2):

This indicates you have run out of virtual memory, try increasing the swap space, or *decreasing* the heap to leave the rest of your program mroe virtual memory.  a 32-bit program is limited to ~3 GB of virtual memory total so if it is all allocated to the heap this doesn't leave much for the program to run in.  By comparison a 64-bit program is limited to 128 TB to 256 TB depending on the OS.

BTW On Windows a 32-bit program is limited to around 1.5 GB of virtual memory.

As hadoop is a big data solution it is typically run on much bigger machines. e.g. 256 GB to 1 TB is not unusual. Given 32 GB is pretty cheap these days I would consider getting at least this much, or a lot more memory.